# How to rewrite URL with Nginx & Orchestra PHP Cloud

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx, orchestra

I'm moving from an Apache environment to the Orchestra PHP Cloud at Engine Yard.  I do not know how to accomadate my URL rewrite rules for my application.  The documentation they supply for this is very limited and basic and can be seen here:

https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21066927-orchestra-php-cloud-service-overview

This is the .htaccess I use today.  I would love some input as to how to go about this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```